# How to bring the © sign in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can bring the © copyright sign in HTML with

```
&copy;
```

How do I bring the © symbol in javascript?

Comment: The copyright symbol is `©`, not `@` , and `&copy;` is an **HTML** entity, not CSS. We've fixed the question to hopefully reflect your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html), for © in html you can use:

```
&copy;
```

In JavaScript use escape sequence (hex code) for any character you need:

```js
var s = "\u00A9"

document.body.innerHTML = s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy it to a string :

```js
var s = "©"

document.body.innerHTML = s
```